# modifying existing code to accept multiple parameters

Tags: javascript

Please refer to the code below for the following Problem description:

```
// Populate a select list with pt codes.
    this.populateCodeList = function (ptName_, listSelector_) {

        if (!ptName_) { return self.displayError("Invalid pt name", "populatecodeList"); }
        if (!listSelector_) { return self.displayError("Invalid list selector", "populatecodeList"); }

        var pt = self.registry.pt[ptName_];

        if (!pt) { return self.displayError("Invalid PT: " + ptName_, "populateCodeList"); }

        var html = "";

        $_.each(pt.codes, function (index_, code) {

            if (!code || !code.id || !code.name) { return self.displayError("Invalid code at index " + index_, "populateCodeList"); }

            html += "<option value='" + code.id + "'>" + code.name + "</option>";
        });

        $_(listSelector_).html(html);
    };
```

**Problem Description:**

I am calling the above function like the following in my code:

```
app_.populateCodeList("First Attribute", self.selectors.add_attribute_dialog + " .attribute-name");
```

Everything works fine. However, when I try to call the above function like this with second attribute separated 
by comma as follows :

```
 app_.populateCodeList("First Attribute,Second Attribute", self.selectors.add_attribute_dialog + " .attribute-name");
```

I get the following error  `Invalid PT:First Attribute,Second Attribute in populateCodeList` which is the result of this line in the above code `if (!pt) { return self.displayError("Invalid PT: " + ptName_, "populateCodeList"); }`

So basically my code is not programmed to handle two parameters separated by comma but single variable which is shown in the line

`var pt = self.registry.pt[ptName_];`

How can I make sure the above line accepts single as well as double parameters whenever needed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split on a delimiter or allow the function consumer to pass an array. Here is an example of the first suggestion:

```
this.populateCodeList = function (ptName_, listSelector_) {

    if (!ptName_) { return self.displayError("Invalid pt name", "populatecodeList"); }
    if (!listSelector_) { return self.displayError("Invalid list selector", "populatecodeList"); }

    var ptNames = ptName_.split(',');
    // if empty, nothing was passed
    if (!ptNames.length) { return self.displayError("No pt names supplied"); }
    // iterate over all matches
    var html = "";

    ptNames.forEach(function(ptName) {
       var pt = self.registry.pt[ptName];
       if (!pt) { return self.displayError("Invalid PT: " + ptName, "populateCodeList"); }

       $_.each(pt.codes, function (index_, code) {

          if (!code || !code.id || !code.name) { return self.displayError("Invalid code at index " + index_, "populateCodeList"); }

          html += "<option value='" + code.id + "'>" + code.name + "</option>";
       });

    });

    $_(listSelector_).html(html);
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Although, I don't see any error while calling it like this ` app_.populateCodeList("First Attribute,Second Attribute", self.selectors.add_attribute_dialog + " .attribute-name");
`  after using your changes, I am seeing information related with `First Attribute` parameter only. If I do it like this ` app_.populateCodeList("Second Attribute,First Attribute", self.selectors.add_attribute_dialog + " .attribute-name");
` I am seeing information related to Second Attribute only and not both. Do you know why it's picking up only first parameter and not both?

Comment: My bad, updated the code. I needed to move `$_(listSelector_).html(html);` outside of the loop, otherwise the last iteration would replcae ALL the html with the html produced in the last iteration.

Comment: Thanks. As soon as I moved it outside the loop, I got `Uncaught ReferenceError: html is not defined` error in browser console.

Comment: I actually updated the code twice, the second edit moved `var html = ''` outside the loop too, if you are using the latest version of the answer it should work for you.

Comment: Awesome. I was missing the `var html - ' '` part. It works perfectly fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

And here is how you would do it passing an array.

```
this.populateCodeList = function (ptNames_, listSelector_) {

    if (!ptNames_) { return self.displayError("Invalid pt name", "populatecodeList"); }
    if (!ptNames_.length) { return self.displayError("Invalid pt name", "populatecodeList"); }

    if (!listSelector_) { return self.displayError("Invalid list selector", "populatecodeList"); }

    var html = "";

    $_.each(ptNames_, function (ptName_) {

        var pt = self.registry.pt[ptName_];

        if (!pt) { return self.displayError("Invalid PT: " + ptName_, "populateCodeList"); }

        $_.each(pt.codes, function (index_, code) {

            if (!code || !code.id || !code.name) { return self.displayError("Invalid code at index " + index_, "populateCodeList"); }

            html += "<option value='" + code.id + "'>" + code.name + "</option>";
        });

    $_(listSelector_).html(html);
};
```

And call it as:

```
app_.populateCodeList(["First Attribute","Second Attribute"], self.selectors.add_attribute_dialog + " .attribute-name");
```

I also find it better to pass (I assume) jQuery elements into functions rather than selectors, i.e:

```
this.populateCodeList = function (ptNames_, $list_) {
   ...
   $list_.html(html);
}

app_.populateCodeList(["First Attribute","Second Attribute"], 
                      $_(self.selectors.add_attribute_dialog + " .attribute-name") );
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, I am getting error on this line `if (!pt) { return self.displayError("Invalid PT: " + ptName_, "populateCodeList"); }
` It says, `Invalid PT : 0 in populateCodeList`.

Comment: Its hard to tell without working code. You might want to try creating a jsfiddle. I would also add some `console.log` statements to check that variables are what you expect.